# On IE 9, window.open is opening a blank window

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, window.open

I am posting my form to another page in a window, using `window.open()`. The problem I have is that when the window opens, it comes blank and the original browser window gets redirected to the page that was supposed to be in the popped up window.

This works fine in Chrome, but IE is not.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks

****EDIT****

I didn't post code because I thought this to be a conceptual question. As I said before, it works on other browsers, but not in IE. So I know my code is working. But if you need a code, here's a sample of it:

The form:

```
<form id="SCartFormId">
  <input type="hidden" name="merchantKey" value="E0FU0E14-CC2D-C88N-6TDQ-0A08CCD05610" />
  <input type="hidden" name="orderNumber" value="321654" />
  <input type="hidden" name="descriptor" value="Test Environment" />
  <input type="hidden" name="cart[0].sku" value="V4C3D5C2" />
  <input type="hidden" name="cart[0].name" value="Halls" />
  <input type="hidden" name="cart[0].unitprice" value="100" />
  <input type="hidden" name="cart[0].quantity" value="10" />
  <input type="hidden" name="shippingMethodCollection[0].name" value="USPS" />
  <input type="hidden" name="shippingMethodCollection[0].price" value="200" />
  <input type="hidden" name="descriptor" value="" />            
</form>
```

The javascript:

```
S.Widgets = {};
S.Widgets.PostWidget = (function(widget){
  var merchantId = widget.merchantId;
  var originForm = widget.orderInput.value;

  var render = (function(target) {var targetHtml = document.getElementById(target),
    button = document.createElement('button'),
    sForm = document.getElementById(originForm);                    

  button.innerText = "Checkout";

  button.onclick = function(){
    window.open('', 'SWidget', 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=yes, width=840, height=840');
    sForm.submit();
  };            
  return {
    render: render
  };
});
```

This button is created on-the-fly with:

```
new S.Widgets.PostWidget({
  merchantId: 'AEIOU1234AEIOU',
  orderInput: {value: 'SCartFormId'}
}).render("sButtonId");
```

Comment: Maybe you should give us some code so that we can track the problem.

Comment: **SHOW YOUR CODE!**

Comment: @epascarello *Maybe I shouldn't try making explicative sentences* :)

Comment: @dystroy Good cop and bad cop.

Comment: We cannot help you unless you show us the code you have written.

Comment: @leobelones You should give us the code real fast, or I won't be able to keep back epascarello and the downvoters. In fact you should realize that you mainly have one chance to get people helping you : you should make your question clear and answerable as soon as possible and never, never, let your question without updates when people comment in the first few minutes.

Comment: I know... I was editing to add some code when you these comments started going crazy... anyways... there they are...

Thanks for any help

Comment: have you tried just _blank instead of SWidget for the window name?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the two lines of code that cause what you describe:

```
// Open a window at URL '' (thus, blank window)
window.open('', 'SWidget', 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=yes, width=840, height=840');

// Submit the form (plain submit, no jQuery.ajax)
// I don't see any jQuery on your code
sForm.submit();
```

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but what about just setting the form's `target` attribute to `_blank`, and removing the `window.open` line?

Comment: Yea, jquery was on the other portion of the code I didn't copy... The jquery/ajax post was just me getting confused explaining on the go with everyone downvoting my question and asking for "code, code, code" like zombies ask for brain! :p

Comment: Or set `target="SWidget"` if you want to reuse the window for multiple posts.

Comment: @leobelones I rejected your edit because my comments still stand, since you didn't show that part of the code. As for the zombies: yes, Stack Overflow can be a bit harsh sometimes. Don't be intimidated by it, but make sure you read the whole [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), and as you post more questions you'll better understand what works better on this site. Reading [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) should also help. Keep in mind that the site's purpose is not to help each individual, but be a resource for future visitors.